# Canvas Optimization

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am drawing multiple text on the canvas in my app. For two text its working fine but drawing multiple text/bitmap at the same times it's a big headache for everyone.it takes all GPU process and it hangs at some point of time especially when you draw large bitmap/text.

Is there any way to save previous drawn things to single bitmap?

```
        @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    if (CustomTextview.GetDB().size() != 0) {
        for (CustomTextview textview : CustomTextview.GetDB()) {
              Bitmap b= drawasbitmap(textview.text,textview.X,textview,Y) //creating a bitmap for view               


                canvas.drawBitmap(b, textview.X, textview.Y, textview.paint);
                b.recycle();




        }
        canvas.restore();

    }

}
```

Lets say i have 5 bitmaps/text in my app.it should draw 5 text at the same time.
         If it's 5 bitmap the memory will go away,is there any way to save all previous view (Bitmap-which is drawn before adding the new one )to one Bitmap ,or can i use drawing cache?

P.S- i have multiple views in my app- i want to draw the recent one for editing purpose .everthing should be saved to temp bitmap and shown to use that views are out there.when ever user clicks that particular region that view get selected called in `onDraw`